# How to investigate drupal_http_request replying 'connection timeout'?

Tags: 7, http-request

Suddenly, my drupal 7 website showed some problem: not able to connect facebook, not able to send mail, not able to contact captcha server. Investigating, i found out that drupal_http_request is reporting a -101 connection timeout error doing

```
drupal_http_request('http://www.google.it');
```

How do i investigate or solve the problem, even if it is a server problem? My website is running on ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: As I mentioned on the previous version of this question, the issue isn't related to Drupal (unless you can provide some information that suggests differently). Solving general server issues are off-topic here, but can be asked on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Thank you, i was trying to be more specific. The previous question was maybe bad presented